# improving site performance

Tags: performance

I have a site http://www.ratingscorner.com/colleges

i have an issue like performance. I think the site is slow. Please see if the speed is feasible . Its o a shared server. what things should i do to increase site/DB performance.

when i try explain command on select command on main table it says like

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  xyz     ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1722    Using where
```

is this okie?

Comment: What is it written in, what database does it use, etc?

Comment: Start out by being more specific about your question.

Comment: flagged -- there is nothing wrong with the site -- seems like an underhanded attempt to draw traffic.  Apologies if my intuition is wrong...

Comment: @hvgotcodes - sorry but i dont want to draw traffic by simply posting here. i had performance problem. so posted.

Comment: @hvgotcodes - the question has 39 views right now and even if 20% really clicked on the link - do you really think this is an attempt to get people to visit your page? To me this is just a question, nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) can usually be enlightening.

Comment: when i say explain the mysql command on my main table it says like 

id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  Extra
1  SIMPLE  xyz  ALL  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  1722  Using where

is this okie.?